# How do I unlock 'A Captainless Squad' part 3?

Tags: valkyria-chronicles-4

After completing both part 1 and part 2, the game popped a warning stating that if I defeat the enemy Aces on both parts, I'd get access to the conclusion of the rest of this Chapter/Extra Story. Both with an A rank.

Thing is, I have defeated the (Ace) Grenadier and the (Ace) Shocktrooper on part 1 and 2 respectively. Do I also have to defeat

> Walz's Vulcan and Crymaria

aswell? If not, why is part 3 not triggering, and how can I trigger it?

Comment: Did you win the battle and defeat the Ace units in the same attempt?